# Elementary interpolation inequality between Lebesgue and Sobolev-Slobodeckij spaces

Tags: fractional-sobolev-spaces, interpolation-theory

Let $W^{s, 2}$ for $0 < s < 1$ denote the Sobolev-Slobodeckij spaces on the interval $(0, 1)$ and $L^2$ the Lebesgue space on the same interval.  I'm interested in an elementary proof that there exists $C > 0$ such that for any $f \in W^{s, 2}$ there holds

$$ \| f \|_{W^{s/2, 2}} \leq C \| f \|_{L^2}^{1/2} \| f \|^{1/2}_{W^{s, 2}}. $$

I'm not super comfortable with interpolation theory, but as far as I know one has $(L^2, W^{s, 2})_{1/2,2} = W^{s/2, 2}$ by the real interpolation method (and reiteration theorem), such that this estimate should be true. I wish to apply a very similar estimate in another context where I cannot use this abstract result directly, which is why I'm interested in an elementary proof of the inequality above.

Let for $0 < s < 1$ the Gagliardo semi-norm of $f \in W^{s, 2}$ be denoted by
$$| f |_{W^{s, 2}} = \left( \int_0^1 \int_0^1 \frac{|f(x) - f(y)|^2}{|x-y|^{2s+1}}\,\mathrm d x \mathrm dy \right)^{1/2}.$$
Then it is sufficient to prove that there is $C > 0$ such that for any $f \in W^{s,2}$ there holds
$$ | f |_{W^{s/2, 2}} \leq C \| f \|_{L^2}^{1/2} | f |^{1/2}_{W^{s, 2}}. $$

I tried to prove this estimate directly, but I can ultimately only prove
$$ | f |_{W^{(s+\mu)/2, 2}} \leq C_\mu \| f \|_{L^2}^{1/2} \| f |^{1/2}_{W^{s, 2}} $$
for $0 < \mu \ll 1$ with $C_\mu \to \infty$ as $\mu \to 0$. Using Hölder's inequality I estimate (omitting the bounds in the integrals for simplicity)
$$\begin{align}
| f |_{W^{(s+\mu)/2, 2}}^2 
&\leq \int \int \frac{| f(x) - f(y) |}{|x - y|^{s+\mu+1}} \left( |f(x)| + |f(y)| \right)\,\mathrm dx \mathrm dy\\
&\leq 2 \int |f(y)| \int \frac{| f(x) - f(y) |}{|x - y|^{s+\mu+1}}\,\mathrm dx \mathrm dy\\
&\leq 2 \left( \int |f(y)|^2 \,\mathrm dy \right)^{1/2} \left( \int \left( \int \frac{| f(x) - f(y) |}{|x - y|^{s+1/2}} \frac{1}{|x-y|^{1/2+\mu}} \,\mathrm dx \right)^2 \mathrm dy \right)^{1/2}\\
&\leq 2 \left( \int |f(y)|^2 \,\mathrm dy \right)^{1/2} \left( \int \int \frac{| f(x) - f(y) |^2}{|x - y|^{2s+1}} \,\mathrm dx \mathrm dy \right)^{1/2} \left( \int \int \frac{1}{|x-y|^{1+2\mu}} \,\mathrm dx\mathrm dy \right)^{1/2}
\end{align}$$

such that

$$ |f|_{W^{(s+\mu)/2,2}} \leq C_\mu \|f \|_{L^2}^{1/2} |f|_{W^{s,2}}^{1/2} \quad\text{with} \quad C_\mu = \sqrt 2 \left( \int \int \frac{1}{|x-y|^{1+2\mu}} \,\mathrm dx\mathrm dy \right)^{1/4}. $$

But there holds $C_0 = \infty$ as the integral in the constant is unbounded for $\mu = 0$.

As an alternative approach I again used only Hölder's inequality to show that for any $0 < \mu \ll 1$ there holds

$$ |f|_{W^{s/2,2}} \leq \operatorname{ess\,sup}_{(x, y) \in (0, 1)^2} | x - y|^{\mu/2} |f |_{W^{\mu, 2}}^{1/2} |f|_{W^{s,2}}^{1/2} $$

but I read in the Hitchhikers Guide to Fractional Sobolev Spaces that only $\lim_{\mu \to 0} \mu |f|^2_{W^{\mu, 2}} = C \| f \|_{L^2}^2$ holds and the essential supremum in the last inequality is actually $1$, so the constant again blows up as $\mu \to 0$.

Comment: For the interval maybe it is easy to use Fourier series? Haven't checked your calc so maybe it runs into the same issue?

Comment: With the Fourier approach the estimate follows easily, which is interesting, thanks for the hint. Looking through the derivation in the Hitchhiker's Guide this seems to stem from the ability to estimate $f(x) - f(y)$ sharply. I would like to see a technique which works using the Gagliardo representation though.

Comment: huh, I wish it was a ‘hint’, which would imply I knew that it would help! Glad to have helped :):) perhaps you could write a sketch as an answer

Comment: might be too early to say but it looks like the bounty didn’t help. Sorry!

Answer (score 3):

Using a Fourier approach the interpolation inequality follows easily. In contrast to the original question I consider the function spaces with domain $\mathbb R^n$ for any $n \in \mathbb N$, the estimate for the interval $(0, 1)$ follows for $n = 1$ since $(0, 1)$ is an extension domain.

According to the Hitchhicker's Guide to Fractional Sobolev Spaces (Prop 3.4), there holds

$$ | u |_{W^{s, 2}(\mathbb R^n)}^2 = C(s, n) \int_{\mathbb R^n} |\xi|^{2s} |\mathcal Fu(\xi)|^2 \,\mathrm d\xi $$

with some factor $C(s, n)$, where $\mathcal F$ denotes the Fourier transform. Then

$$ \begin{align}
| u |_{W^{s/2, 2}(\mathbb R^n)}^2 
&= C(s/2, n) \int_{\mathbb R^n} |\xi|^{s} |\mathcal Fu(\xi)|^2 \,\mathrm d\xi \\
& \leq C(s/2, n) \left( \int_{\mathbb R^n} |\xi|^{2s} |\mathcal Fu(\xi)|^2 \,\mathrm d\xi \right)^{1/2} \left( \int_{\mathbb R^n} |\mathcal Fu(\xi)|^2 \,\mathrm d\xi \right)^{1/2}\\
& \leq C(s/2, n) C(s, n)^{-1/2} |u|_{W^{s, 2}(\mathbb R^n)} \| u \|_{L^2(\mathbb R^n)}
\end{align}$$
using Hölder's inequality and Plancherel's theorem.

While this answers the original question I'm still very interested in how one can directly argue using the Gagliardo semi-norm.